# What is a safe way to "bound" environment variable in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, environment-variables

Suppose we have a library `A` witch behavior depends on value of some
environment variable.  `A_CONFIG_PATH` actually. Some of my tasks use
this library with different `A_CONFIG_PATH` for each task. I do it in a
way of

```
import os
import A

def task(**kw):
    os.environ['A_CONFIG_PATH'] = '/home/me/current/task/config/path'
    A.do_some_stuff(kw)
```

This fine until all tasks process synchronously.  But now I need
concurrency in this tasks processing.

So how I can guarantee that each task will not corrupt another with 
its own A_CONFIG_PATH if I run each task in separate thread/process
or something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to tackle the problem:

1. run each task in a subprocess, instead all in one process in different threads
2. change the task to take the `A_CONFIG_PATH` value as a parameter, instead of reading it from environment (reading from env is just as bad as relying on global variables...)
3. instead of assigning a string to `os.environ[A_CONFIG_VALUE]`, use a [`threading.local`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local) object, which allows each thread to have its own value. You'd need to slightly change the part which reads the value, though.

An example using `threading.local`:

```
#one time init
os.environ['A_CONFIG_PATH'] = threading.local()

# set the value    
def task(**kw):
    os.environ['A_CONFIG_PATH'].value = '/home/me/current/task/config/path'
    A.do_some_stuff(kw)

# read the value
config_path = os.environ['A_CONFIG_PATH'].value
```

EDIT: since you said the env var is being read using `os.getenv`, you can combine the third solution with this hack, replacing `os.getenv` with your own:

```
# one time init
orig_getenv = os.getenv
def getenv_hacked(key, default=None):
    if key == 'A_CONFIG_PATH':
       return orig_getenv(key, default).value
     else:
       return orig_getenv(key, default)
os.getenv = getenv_hacked
os.environ['A_CONFIG_PATH'] = threading.local()
```

Comment: The problem actually is that `A` library use this variable by `os.getenv('A_CONFIG_PATH')`, not my code. So is third way still appropriate in this case?

Comment: The solution #3 doesn't work for me, but I can't format the ipython output properly, so see the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348556/