# Set different environment variables per thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, environment-variables, proxies

I was wondering if it is possible to run threads each with its own environment variables.

I am currently using environment variables to set my proxies like this:

```
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = proxy["http"]
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = proxy["https"]
```

But I noticed that each thread will just use the proxy that has last been set. It is not possible for me to use the requests library for this purpose.

Is there a way that I can achieve this without using `requests.Session()` for each thread?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348556/how-to-set-a-thread-specific-environment-variable-in-python

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Environment variables were never meant as a means of communication between threads. They are meant as a way for something outside the program to pass in configuration info. If you are using a library that forces you to use the environment as the only means of passing in parameters, then proceed with caution! That might be a sign that the library is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if it is possible to run threads each with its own
> environment variables.

No. Env vars live in the address space of the process and thus are global to all threads of the process.